# Silbentrennung bei Gender-Formen

Tags: gender-neutrality, hyphenation

Wie soll man Gender-Formen trennen, sei es solche mit Binnen-I, mit Binnen-Doppelpunkt oder sonstige?

```
Mit-ar-bei-te-rIn-nen
```

weil so auch die im Schriftbild zu 99% übereinstimmende weibliche Form getrennt wird?

```
Mit-ar-bei-ter-In-nen
```

weil so am beim Sprechen eingeführten Kehlkopfschluss getrennt wird (und zugleich am Ende des maskulinen Teilabschnitts)?

Entsprechend:

```
Mit-ar-bei-te-r:in-nen
```

oder

```
Mit-ar-bei-ter-:in-nen
```

oder gar (wenn auch der Idee mit dem Kehlkopfschlusslaut widersprechend)

```
Mit-ar-bei-ter:-in-nen
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es gibt dafür (wen wundert's) keine verbindliche Regel, weil die gesamte Genderei von der etablierten Grammatik und Orthographie abgelehnt oder bestenfalls ignoriert wird. „Korrekt“ in einem verbindlich-präskriptiven Sinn ist das alles nicht; man wird sich also vom eigenen Ästhetikempfinden und ähnlichen Beweggründen leiten lassen müssen.

`Mit-ar-bei-te-rIn-nen` ist jedenfalls furchtbar (wie ja das Binnen-I an sich, aber das führt hier zu weit). Wie wäre es mit `Mitarbeiter und Mitarbeiterinnen`, ggf. verkürzt zu `Mitabeiter und -‍innen`? Das lässt sich dann auch problemlos umbrechen.

Comment: Dumm nur, wenn einE AutorIn mir einen Text vor den Latz knallt, den ich tpyografisch aufbereiten soll, und ein Wort mit Binnen-I dadurch zur Trennung ansteht ... :(

Comment: Eine einzige problematische Trennung (und wenn Eingriffe in den Text in jeder Form, Umformulierungen o.ä. keine Option sind) lässt sich eigentlich immer auf microtypographischer Ebene verhindern. Oder man trennt eben dort, wo es eindeutig zulässig ist, `Mit-//arbeiterInnen` oder `Mitarbei-//terInnen`; oder wenn es gar nicht anders geht `Mitarbeiter-//Innen`. Ab er es gibt hier mE keine klaren Regeln, und persönlich empfinde ich `Mitarbeite-//rInnen` als die schlechteste Wahl.

Comment: Am Ende hat sich hier herausgestellt, dass ohnehin die unproblematische Trennung vor -nen vom Satzprogramm gegenüber beiden fraglichen Trennungen bevorzugt wurde :) Danke trotzdem

Answer (score 1):

Das Gendern mit Binnen-I, Stern, Unterstrich oder Doppelpunkt besteht grammatisch einfach nur in der Ersetzung des vorher verwendeten generischen Maskulinums durch das neu zu benutzende generische Femininum, nur mit einer orthographischen Kenntlichmachung, die deutlich machen soll, dass andere Geschlechter mitgemeint sind. (In letzterem besteht dann der enorme Gerechtigkeitsfortschritt, der es das alles wert macht - also zumindest ist das die Sprachregelung der Feministinnen, die sich das überlegt haben.)

*Grund-/männliche Form => abgeleitete weibliche Form => "gerechte" Form*
Mitarbeiter => Mitarbeiterin => Mitarbeiter_in
Arzt => Ärztin => Ärzt_in (nicht etwa eine Vereinigung der Eigenschaften wie Arzt_in oder sowas)
Ärzte => Ärztinnen = Ärzt_innen (nicht etwa Ärzte_innen oder sowas)

Daraus folgt, dass die richtige Trennung natürlich die der weiblichen Form ist, um die es sich ja schlicht und einfach handelt:

> Mit-ar-bei-te-r_in-nen

Jede andere Lösung wäre für das angestrebte Gerechtigkeitsniveau  unzureichend.

Comment: Du meinst hoffentlich FeministInnen, du KoryphäeRich :)

Comment: Eigentlich genau nicht, weil diese Konstruktion ja eben genau aus weiblicher Sicht definiert wurde. Wobei es laut Wikipedia eventuell tatsächlich ein Mann war, der zum ersten Mal das bis dahin übliche Feminist/-innen (das schon dieselben Probleme hatte) zu FeministInnen zusammengezogen hat.